# Are Discrete Graphic Cards needed to run Unity 3D?

Tags: graphics

I was using 10.04, upgraded to 12.04 15 days before. 
My system specifications are:

512 MB Ram ( 2 slots each of 256 MB 184pin DDR DIMM RAM )
i686, AMD Athlon ( 1150 MHZ ), without graphics card.

I am a normal user. I want to upgrade my system ( I don't want to buy a new one )
to 2 GB RAM ( 1+1 GB). There is a slot for AGP3 graphics card. But Is Graphic card necessary for Ubuntu 12.04 ?

Comment: Better way would be run `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` to check if Unity 3d is supported by your system or not.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Motherboard comes with inbuilt Graphics Module, minimum though but enough to run **Ubuntu / Linux** based system. You mentioned slower system performance , it would be mostly due to RAM (DDR 1st version) as mentioned..

To check if your system supports Unity 3D run

```
 /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

If result is positive , then continue with RAM upgrading , it will perform better for sure.

If you want more smoother performance consider [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) for less resource hungry Desktop Environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need one graphic card to run any operating system. Doesn't matter if it's built in, AGP, PCI, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

There is always an integrated graphics processor which gives you a display. Some of these graphics card are capable of running ubuntu 3D.

It will be better if you create a live usd/disk of 12.04 and test in your system.

Comment: I have already Installed Ubuntu 12.04  through DVD. It's working But little slow. Unity 2D

Comment: Check whether there is any additional drivers for it. Or post output of `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: So your computer has to have some graphic card built in. You should see if that graphic card can run Unity 3D like tijybba said